# What are the status codes returned for SSR redirect in Next.js?

Tags: redirect, next.js

I'm using Next `redirect` object which allows redirecting (inside `getServerSideProps`), and trying to understand what status code is returned in response.

The only hint I found in [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect) is:

> In some rare cases, you might need to assign a custom status code for
> older HTTP clients to properly redirect.

So what status code is returned by default with this implementation? There are multiple code relevant to redirecting (301, 302, 307 and more), and I found conflicting claims in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of the possible status codes that Next.js will return based on what happens in the process of server-side rendering:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/db9040b0b85b6e111543de516961e0249faaf0e8/packages/next/pages/_error.tsx#L5

```
const statusCodes = {
  400: 'Bad Request',
  404: 'This page could not be found',
  405: 'Method Not Allowed',
  500: 'Internal Server Error',
}
```

You can also specify your own `statusCode` prop as part of returning an error/redirect from Next.js.

EDIT: Adding from @juliomalves, the default status codes are 307 (permanent: false) and 308 (permanent: true) for redirect!

Comment: Thanks. According to the doc, in order to provide custom status code, I should use statusCode property instead of the permanent property.